# How to get roles of GuildMember and their information

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot3 = new Discord.Client();

const token3 = 'I am not telling my bots token';
const mark2 = '*info personal'
bot3.on('message', msg =>{
    let args2 = msg.content.substring(mark2.length).split('')
    if (msg.content.startsWith(mark2)){
        const hashitag = msg.author.id
        const actualhashitag = msg.author.discriminator
        const evenbetterhashitag = "#" + actualhashitag 
        const personalembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Stuff about you')
            .setImage(msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setColor('#D11111')
            .addField('Your username',  msg.author.username)
            .addField('Your hashtag', hashitag, true)
            .addField('Your actual hashtag', actualhashitag, true)
            .addField('Your even realer hashtag', evenbetterhashitag, true)   
            .addField('Your amount of friends', 'Discord bots can not know that sadly')
            .addField('Your role', )
        msg.channel.send(personalembed)
    }

})

bot3.login(token3)
```

How would I get message author's roles in the current guild?
When I searched up roles I only found how to check if someone has a role or get everyone with a role.
I have opened up a space for it. I'm pretty sure I'll need more fields for it.

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles

Comment: Can you ellaborate.I didn't exactly find the awnser I wanted. I would prefer you just straight out telling me how then me trying to find the awnser with no avail. I appreciated the edit though.

Comment: Are you using Discord.js V12?

Comment: I know I might seem dumb but how are you supposed to find out the version of discord.js you're using?

Comment: Go to package.json and check dependencies.

Comment: Oh I see. Well I have version 12.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discord.js Version 11:

### Getting Roles

```
message.member.roles.map(role => role.name).join(", ")
//Result: Role1, Role2, Role3, Role4 etc...
```

Discord.js Version 12:

### Getting Roles

```
message.member.roles.cache.map(role => role.name).join(", ")
//Result: Role1, Role2, Role3, Role4 etc...
```

---

roles / roles.cache is a Collection, therefore we can use its method called "map" which maps each item to another value into an array. Then, using .join() on the array to transform it into a string, containing the information we need. The first argument of .join() is the separator.

Example:

```js
const Array = ["Role 1", "Role 2", "Role 3"];

console.log(Array.join(", "))
```

```js
const Array = ["Role 1", "Role 2", "Role 3"];

console.log(Array.join(" | "))
```

As I said before, map() maps each item to another value into an array.

```
message.member.roles.cache.map(role => role.id)
// Array containing all GuildMember's role IDs
// ["567354370534056", "54673456894325763", "129346934643805364"]

message.member.roles.cache.map(role => role.name)
// Array containing all GuildMember's role names
// ["Role1", "Role2", "Role3"]
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'll take a screenshot because this might be important later and I don't want to have to ask this again.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Message.author` you get a user object: to get the roles of that user you need to use the `GuildMember` object, which you can get with `Message.member`. Here's an example:

```js
let authorUser = message.author,
  authorMember = message.member

let authorRoles = authorMember.roles.cache // Collection<Snowflake, Role>
```

As you can see, I used [`GuildMember.roles.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache) to get the collection of roles: you can then use it to do whatever you want.

Comment: How do I get the actual roles(the roles you assign to people in discord) from it though. I tried seeing it's contents by saying console.log(msg.member.roles.cache) an here is what i got(It's too long to show here). How do i extract the actual roles from it. I did find a roles part. It only said [RoleManager] though which is not what i want.

Comment: Well, that is a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), a structure that is used a lot in discord.js. You already have the roles, it's just that you have to access them through a Collection method (which are listed in the docs). If you don't want to use them you can also convert the Collection to an array with the [`array`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=array) method: that would be `let rolesArray = authorMember.roles.cache.array()`

Comment: Makes sense. 123

Comment: @mataldin Did that solve your problem? If that's the case, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick on the left: this way the question will be marked as solved

Comment: I ticked another message that was sent before this. I ticked Jakye's response because it's the first message that popped up and gave me the awnser. The one that has two code snippets.

Comment: Oooops, sorry, i didn't see that